# Use a European halogen electric light fixture in the U.S.

Tags: voltage

I brought a halogen standing light fixture home to the U.S. from Europe.  The light worked using an adapter to convert the Euro plug to the U.S. plug, but the light was dim.  I read that the wattage of the Euro bulbs was specified based on the 220V in Europe so i replaced the bulbs with US rated bulbs ( 300 W) and the light worked perfectly for a while. The main torch light stopped working but the task light continues to work.  I tried another bulb in the fixture and it does not work either.

There is a T2.5AH 250V fuse in the fixture that, when removed, turns off the task lamp.

Does the fuse have to change to correspond to the 120V?  Do i have to replace anything else in the lamp to make it work?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Fuse is pretty much fine electrically but may not be up to code in the US and you are running it at pretty much 100% rated current. What socket/base did the bulb have? Be aware that E27 is common in Europe and E26 in the US. It pretty much fits but creates a latent fire hazard.

Answer (score 1):

The 300W  bulb draws up to 3kW peak when cold.  When reducing voltage from 230 to 120 the same wattage doubles current. Most likely something did not handle the excess heat from higher currents.  ( triac dimmer? or switch?)

The  2.5A fuse must be doubled for same power at half the voltage, but can the wiring and switches support that?  Maybe not.  The H suffix means time delay or "slow-blow"

Are these the long halogen tubes? 119mm EU is compatible  with 4.7" US
 (same)

@Winny 's warning is true for Edison style screw base because the 1mm difference between the threads of E26 and E27 can cause unsafe higher resistance contacts that rises with aging and oxidation of heat.

Comment: Thanks, these are the long halogen tubes.  How do I know if the switch is bad?